# How to maximize an application after minimize

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to maximized my application after 10 seconds when user minimized my app`(com.myapp.app1)`
 on Android . and I used this Code in the timer:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.myapp.app1");
if (launchIntent != null) {
   startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

and I used this code too:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.myapp.app1");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addCategory(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startActivity(i);
```

both of them works correct when user maximize `com.myapp.app1`,  but when user minimize `com.myapp.app1` and after that open another app (for example : app2) and minimize it, after 10 seconds , app2 maximize instead of `com.myapp.app1`.

what should I do ?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: It is a Taximeter , I want maximize that all the time. why  this code " i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.myapp.app1");startActivity(i);  "   shows another app  ?

Comment: You might want to look into the screen pinning feature that was introduced with Android 5.0: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#ScreenPinning